# Python, how to check if a >= b for 5 seconds ? I used while loops and got delays in other functions

Tags: python, while-loop, raspberry-pi3

I'm an absolute noob in python and mostly in programming too. (so be critics I hope I can learn from that too)

I'm trying to create my "program" on a Raspberry Pi 3, with Raspbian OS

My problem is the following:

I'd like to test "if a >= b for 5 seconds" (where "a" is a value which I read out from the serial in an other function)

if yes do something if not do something else, to be seems really simple...

I all ready "party" solved it once in my code with a while loop in one of my functions, but when I copied the "time waiting while loop" to my other function it started to generate a huge delay (it's about the same amount of time which I was adding to my extra while loops)

I really hope someone could suggest me any other way to check "if a >= b for 5 seconds" other than a while loop

or if someone would have some free time to check on my code and tell me what mistakes I made (probably a lot of noob mistakes)

Here's my code which does not contains the critical 2 while loops (just one with 30 seconds delay)

```
`https://pastebin.com/RmEcLRJA`
```

And here's the other with the 2 extra while loops, which seems to be delaying the measurements (of my xwatts variable) with about 6-14 seconds in total (I gave 3 seconds delay in each while loop)

```
`https://pastebin.com/HB99vH9c`
```

P.S. sorry for the links my code is quiet long to paste here twice

My value "a" is a constantly changing value, it updates in less than 1 second, I need to know if a >= b for 5 seconds constantly, if it drops for 1 reading only (0.1 sec) it must restart the 5 seconds "timer"

Comment: Welcome to SO, you will get more answer if you create a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Stack Overflow usually makes the code scrollable if it's too long, it's a fun little formatting thing. Though if you want to do links, you use a `[]` `()` syntax, where in the `[]`'s hold the text you want to show as the hyperlink and the `()`'s hold the actual link, [as so](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Although if you can create a smaller example that better shows what you're struggling with, that will be easier for readers to help you with.

Comment: Yeah that link formatting does not work with pasebin links...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *while*:

```
import time
end_time = time.time() + 5
while 'Wait 5 seconds':
    if a >= b:
       ...

    if time.time() > end_time:
        break
```

Also removing all `time.sleep()` within the code will solve your delay issue.

Comment: Isn't it due to all your `time.sleep()`? Have you draw your logic? Maybe it's just an algorithm issue.

Comment: If I run the 1 while loop delay version it's working perfectly, so I think it's not caused by the the "time.sleep()" so since when I use simple "if" without the "while loops" to count time  it's measuring in real time actually

Comment: My value "a" is a constantly changing value, it updates in less than 1 second, I need to know if a >= b for 5 seconds constantly, if it drops for 1 reading only (0.1 sec) it must restart the 5 seconds "timer"

Comment: @VikTor if so then do not put any sleep into this while. Otherwise you are only measuring at a low frequency during these 5s.

Comment: It starts to make sense for me too, unfortunately I'm not able to test it right now, but I hope it will work tomorrow after I'll remove the `time.sleep()`. I was thinking I need those `time.sleep(0.001)` to prevent the while from using a lot of CPU power when it's "counting time"

Comment: @VikTor well on my system, this is not an issue. Plus if you really need these update I can't think of an alternative. Hope our discussion helped.

Comment: After thinking it over and over again (with my noob programmer logic) your idea makes more and more sense... I run this scrip only (but nothing else) on a Raspberry Pi 3, I just don't want to burn the RPi, it's installed into a metal cabinet (with a huge cooling fan) at a huge industrial hall (I made this code to control a custom plastic recycling/crushing machine) I hope the CPU won't get too hot

Comment: @VikTor glad I could help. Consider validate the answer to close the issue for everyone. You will not burn everything, the CPU would shut down automatically in case of critical temperature. I run this kind of loops on HPC so no worries ;) It is true that an empty loop will cause a 100% CPU but you are doing some stuff to occupy it. And even if it was the case, it is just 5sec.

Comment: You were party right. I removed all the `time.sleep()` and the delay in my measuring callback just went down from 10-12 seconds to 5-6 seconds. So your idea/logic made a lot of sense, I learned a lot from it, thanks again for your time and effort ;-) But since I have not had any more time left to tweak my code, and our electro tech. guy recommended to use an analog timer between the relay and the motor (which we would like to switch only when the measured value is constantly over "b") so we solved this problem with the analog timer